# esrcript cron blues

Tags: cron, erlang, erlang-escript

I have an escript file which runs fine from the command line, i.e.:

```
./escript_file
```

It is meant to be cron friendly and all paths are explicit but when I run it, it fails to compile saying that there are `bad attributes`.

The bad attributes in question are macro definitions:

```
-define(COOKIE, 'somecookie').
```

**The Answer**

Thanks to Geoff Ready's suggestion I investigated which version of Erlang was running by printing out `init:script_id()` which prints out a string like `{"OPT APN 181 O1", "R13B"}` and, sure enough the command line and cron versions were picking up different versions.

The script had an initial line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
```

and the operating system was 'finding' Erlang for me. The different environment variables of cron meant that a different erlang was being picked up (Geoff's first answer, and one I kinda knew but couldn't see how it would affect things).

The solution is then to force the version with a starting line of:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/erlang/erts-5.7.3/bin/escript
```

**Postscript**

There was also a different Ubuntu `apt-get` install of an earlier version of Erlang (in a different location to the source install) and an errant 64-bit install...

The cron environment just kept falling back to older and more obscure installs, failing all the while :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps cron is picking up a different version of erlang in the path. [Erlang R12B documentation](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/erts-5.6/doc/html/escript.html) says that escript ignores preprocessor directives besides include_lib. [Erlang R13B documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html) says that the preprocessor is run on the file. That would definitely explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: Indeed we have installed R13B over R11B and escript is picking up R11B and the command line is picking up R13B

Answer (score 3):

If it is working fine from the command line, a likely cause is a difference in environment variables for your interactive shell versus when cron runs the script.

Comment: That was my first thought, it is the normal problem with cron. But it is not clear at all how the environment variables could cause a failure of the compile part of the code to execute a define which is a language construct in Erlang.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `#!/usr/bin/env escript` to `#!/usr/local/bin/escript` at the top of the file will work if the Erlang versions are the same.